# What's the best programmatic approach to mirror facebook page feed to a Whatsapp channel?

Tags: python, facebook, api, whatsapp

I have a facebook page which posts image content regularly on it's feed. I want to create a Whatsapp account (preferably a bot) which people can subscribe to with a message, and start receiving all the new posts on the page as Whatsapp message from that number.

The following is the approach I want to follow.

1. Create a subscription mechanism: Save the contact number of all users who send 'SUBSCRIBE' to my number to a broadcast list.
2. Use facebook graph API to check for new posts on my facebook page feed.
3. If there is a new post on the page feed, send the content to broadcast lists created in second step.

The second step can be easily done in python using the well documented graph api. The first and third step however seems complicated as the Whatsapp business API access is subject to approvals and the third party solutions are not well documented. What would be the best approach to implement the first and third steps mentioned above, preferably in python?